# Link going transparent

Tags: html, css

I am currently building a website and as soon as I added a link `<a>` tag to a `<p>` word, it becomes transparent. There are two links on the main page, both are coded exactly the same, but one of the links is transparent? The html passes validation and so does the css. If I add the old school `<font color>` html property within the `<a>` the color shows up, but the words break apart on different lines. I know this way is obsolete, but no CSS is working right now? Help?

Comment: If you could isolate the HTML and CSS to the smallest example where the problem is still happening, post the code and you'll get better answers.

Comment: Code is missing. From the description I'd say some style-information is creating that. Disable author styles so that you only have browser styles. They normally display links.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the background color is not the same as the hyperlink colors.

For kicks, try this: `<font face="verdana" color="green">[your-entire-hyperlink-code]</font>`

That's not how it should be done, but just to test it. If you see text, then your background color and hyperlink color are the same and need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a CSS selector for `<a>` tags within `<p>` tags. Something like the following:

```
p a {
  color: #000;
  }
p a:hover {
  color: #1c1c1c;
  }
```

This should make any `<a>` black by default, and a dark grey on hover. If this doesn't work, try disabling all styles save for the default browser style-sheet (like Hakre said).